# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, flask, flask-migrate

I try to test `friend route` for my flask application, but got the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
```

I could test the model but when I want to test flask ('You are now Friend with ') I get the error above.

I am not expert in flask testing.

Can you tell me what is wrong and how can I fix it?

view.py:

```
@layout.route('/friend/<name>')
@login_required
def friend(name):
        user = Users.query.filter_by(name = name).first()
        if user == g.user:
            flash('You can\'t Friend yourself!')
            return redirect(url_for('layout.user',page=1,sortby='normal'))
        u = g.user.be_friend(user)
        if u is None:
            flash('You have been Friend with ' + name + '.')
            return redirect(url_for('layout.user',page=1,sortby='normal'))
       db.session.add(u)
       db.session.commit()
       flash('You are now Friend with ' + name + '!')
       return redirect(url_for('layout.user', page=1,sortby='normal'))
```

test.py:

```
 def test_friend(self):
        u1 = Users(name='monk1', email='monk1@example.com', age=25)
        u2 = Users(name='monk2', email='monk2@example.com', age=27)
        db.session.add(u1)
        db.session.add(u2)
        db.session.commit()
        response = self.assertTrue(u1.be_friend(u2))
        self.assertTrue('You have been Friend with monk2', response.data)
# I got error Here if I comment this line the test whole model.py works well But Now I want to test flash too that I get the mentioned error
```

Comment: Post your traceback so we can see the error

Comment: Where is your `be_friend(user)` method? Can you post its source?

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
self.assertTrue('You have been Friend with monk2', response.data)
```

the value of response in the previous step has been set to `None`, as the result of `response = self.assertTrue(u1.be_friend(u2))` is `None`. The `assertTrue` would raise an error if the condition was not met, and so nothing is returned as its output, and hence the value of `response` is `None`.

Since `None` doesn't have any attribute named `data`, the error is thrown.

Comment: how u know that the value of self.assertTrue(u1.be_friend(u2)) is None? @mu

Comment: Because assertTrue doesn't return anything.

Comment: and How can I test the flash thanx if u help @mu

Comment: @DanielRoseman When a method doesn't return anything, and you still call it and assign its value to a variable, the variable will be set to `None`, right?

Comment: @LILI Were you able to resolve this? If my answer helped, don't forget to [accept and upvote it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the `be_friend` method:

```
def be_friend(self, user): #follow
    if not self.are_friends(user):
        self.is_friend.append(user)
        user.is_friend.append(self)
        return self
```

Here, if both users are already friends, you return nothing (hence Python automatically returns None). You can possibly fix it by changing your method to:

```
def be_friend(self, user): #follow
    if not self.are_friends(user):
        self.is_friend.append(user)
        user.is_friend.append(self)
    return self
```

Also, using `assertIsNotNone` instead of `assertTrue` would help you catch this bug.

You also cannot assign the return value as an HTTP response object since you are calling your method directly, not your view. You may rewrite your test as follows:

```
self.assertIsNotNone(u1.be_friend(u2))
self.assertTrue(u1.are_friends(u2))
```

Comment: Same error ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peg/flask-Alembic/test/test_app.py", line 82, in test_friend
    self.assertTrue('You have been Friend with monk2', response.data)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
@Selcuk

Comment: Ok, are you trying to get the HTTP response in your test? It is not how unittest works. You are calling the method directly, not your view. See my updated answer.

Comment: thanx Now I get this errorAssertionError: False is not true @Selcuk :(

Comment: Then your tests are running good. Either `be_friend` or `are_friends` method is broken.

Comment: But shouldn't the coverage  increase or at leadt shows the this test is ok instead of  errorAssertionError: False is not true  ?? @Selcuk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71786/discussion-between-lili-and-selcuk).